# UITabbarcontroller switching problem

Tags: iphone

I have created a tab bar application. In that application, I have three tab bar items. Each tab bar controller has a navigation controller. I have pushed two `UIViewController` from first tab bar item (using navigationcontroller) that named new `UIViewController`. Now I want to move from  new UIViewController to the third tabbar item.

I'm using the code below:

```
self.tabbarcontroller.selectedindex = 2;
[self.navigationcontroller poptoviewcontroller:YES];
```

But it crashes often. What could be the reason?

Comment: please elaborate your question.It is not understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you pop the view controller?

Just make the change in the tabbar controller and use this code to switch between tabs:

```
self.tabbarcontroller.selectedindex = 2;
```

Comment: This is not working. it will come to third tabbar item but when i go to first tabbaritem its in new UIViewController as i said above.I dont want like that ,after it goes to third tabbaritem then i press first tabbaritem it pops back to mainviewcontroller not stay at any subviewcontroller.

Comment: You need to handle this in the tabbars delegate method then, and do PopToRoot (I think it is). I dont have code to hand but will post later when on Mac

Comment: use this code in
-(void) viewDidDisappera{ 
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]  animated:YES];
}